# Getting DropDownList Value is generating strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList on a page

```
<select name="Pages1$RadPanelBar1$i0$i0$ddlParentPage" id="Pages1_RadPanelBar1_i0_i0_ddlParentPage" tabindex="2">
    <option value="0">[main menu]</option>
    <option value="1">Home</option>
    <option value="3">Getting Connected</option>
    <option value="5">Communications</option>
    <option value="35">Sitemap</option>
    <option value="46">SlideShow</option>
 </select>
```

The problem I am having is that the following code is setting **ParentID** to 0 (which to me, obviously shouldn't be happening)

```
    'get parent page
    Dim ParentID As Integer = Nothing
    Dim DDLValue As Integer = Integer.Parse(ddlParentPage.SelectedItem.Value)
    If DDLValue > 0 Then
        ParentID = ddlParentPage.SelectedItem.Value
    End If
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: is Dim ParentID As Integer = Nothing the right thing ?

Comment: Yes because the end result is that I am inserting it into a database.  If I enter "Nothing" into the database, the result is "Null", which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I fixed it with SQL instead of code... too lazy to figger it out, and it's super late :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I answered this problem using SQL instead of Code.

I completely removed the IF statement in the code and just submitted the ddl.selecteditem.value into the database Stored Procedure.

From there I did a SQL IF Statement

```
    IF @ParentID = 0
Begin
    Insert Into icms_Pages
        (
            ParentID,

        )
    Values
        (
            Null,

        )
END
ELSE
    Insert Into icms_Pages
        (
            ParentID,

        )
    Values
        (
            @ParentID,
```